# Java call hierarchy analysis

Tags: java, struts

Are there any tools out there that I could use to help me in analyzing call hierarchies of Java code?  I am essentially looking for a way to select a method, generate the hierarchy, and then serialize to disk the highest level pieces of the hierarchy paths (all the roots) so that I can get some stats on it and get a better idea of risk/testing effort if this code were to be refactored.

My end goal is for any given method in a Java web app (no matter what layer it's in), figure out all the entry points into the application (Struts actions, web services) that a given method is utilized by. Eclipse has a nice tool that I use all the time for call hierarchies, but the method I'm analyzing is so heavily utilized that it won't be practical for me to go through manually expanding the trees and typing everything by hand.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using logger, and analyze the log at what perspective you desire (using baregrep or some similar tool).

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, but I think trying to use a logger to investigate invoked paths (stack traces) has the potential to leave out a lot of code execution paths that may not have been invoked yet that are still applicable to my requirement.  I am dealing with around 300 or more entry points.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/).  It's a tool to monitor test coverage but there's no reason it can't be used for what you need.  The reports ([sample report](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/sample/frame-summary.html)) are very comprehensive, allowing you to drill down to see which lines were executed and now many times.

A similar tool is [Emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net/index.html), which has been updated more recently than Cobertura.  I've never used Emma so I can't comment on how well it works.  The [sample report](http://emma.sourceforge.net/coverage_sample_a/index.html) looks similar to Cobertura's.